# Insulted Allah?

Tags: allah, shirk, punishment, shaitan, waswasa

I have been suffering from waswas. I feel like it’s a jinn and shaytaan whispering it . I always seek refuge in them and praise Allah . And Allah always guides me  and helps me . Today I woke up and was very tired and I was meant to insult myself due to a stupid mistake I did earlier today and the insult turned into an insult to Allah ??? Abs I felt like I controlled it . Like I’m the one that changed it to insult Allah !  I know I did it surely they can’t control my mind ??? I get bad thoughts sometimes which I don’t understand how I think but this was worse ..And I hated it. I feel like crying. I already know I’m nothing . But I feel even more worse . How could I do that ? I actually hate it. Allah is so merciful and pure and the greatest . And I had a bad thought which I feel I controlled ! Astaghfirullah. I also find around music I get worse thoughts today at work I was told to disbelieve in my mind.  But I didn’t mean that but this thought was different I feel like I insulted ! Also when I listen to ruqya I kept getting bad bad bad thoughts. Please ask Allah to help me .

Comment: Also when I try to praise Allah and thank Him for everything He has given me and trying to think good of others the opposite comes in my mind. When I try to say may Allah bless him and intend to make dua for him some bad thought comes in . When I praise Allah for everything my mind tells me it was all down to me ? When I know it wasn’t .

Comment: Two days in a row now I woke up and my mind is telling me to disbelieve ?... but in my heart I will never . Allah is one .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, allah is with you, whatever comes to your mind this is not your intention, this is not in your heart, so Allah will not angry with you, you are trying your best to keep him happy that's why he loves you. Allah knows your intention, he knows best what is in your heart, you are not sinful for this. So, whenever these thoughts come to your mind immediately start thinking about something else, anything you like.

Comment: I said it . Something bad . But I didn’t finish it off but my mind did ? But it wasn’t in my control ? But I hated it ? And idk why??? Like saying it I didn’t mean it

Comment: Just try to ignore them

Comment: I am really confused. I find myself thinking stuff that I hate and don’t mean. I praise Allah and I think bad stuff like give me punishment. Which I hate . And I need to stay away from . I really hate that . When I don’t believe it . One bit. I regret it straight away but I really feel it came from me . Also I found someone has done nazr on me and signs of jinn posession. Make dua for me brothers .

Comment: Is it shirk to say in my mind gift to Allah by praising him  ??? I thought of it but I repented . Because Allah doenst meed us or our praise. But Is it shirk ???I keep having these bad thoughts that I don’t know if I agree with and I don’t like it . I need help

Comment: Don't worry you are not doing any sin ,just remember allah is with you. Keep smile on your face and don't forget that Allah loves you. Allah wants ease for us not difficulty. Just keep trying to keep him happy and forget all the worries ,he just sees how best we are trying to keep Allah happy.

Comment: Why is my mind telling me to challenge Allah ???? I hate it . I will never . I say out loud I submit to him . I have no idea why it is saying that . I feel like I’m saying that .... not a waswas.

Comment: I hate this . I was thinking about musa as abs how Allah helped him and disgraced firaun as he terrorised Allahs prophet and slave musa as abs after I said that in my mind I kept trying to avoid saying son in mind as I don’t believe in it and Ik I get these thoughts in my mind and I said it in my mind and I don’t believe it at all and I hate that this is happening. Is this shirk ? I hated it but I felt like  I felt I had to say it in my mind to get rid of it . I felt like I was fighting my mind but I had to give in ???

Comment: Do you know you are doing jihad you are fighting against your thoughts to keep allah happy, I don't know that how to get rid of these thoughts but I know that you are not doing any shirk

Comment: I literally keep thinking of insults to Allah . I am literally fighting my own stupid nafs. It thinks of bad bad things of Allah and I try my best. I don’t like it . I need help.

Comment: My mind cursed but I didn’t mean or think ???

Comment: So, why are you worried?

Comment: Because I get such despicable bad thoughts about Allah and I feel like I believe them . And I hate that I believed in them and it makes me so upset because they are such bad thoughts that would make you lose ur imaan.

Comment: If you hate those thoughts then you don't need to worry , and don't think that you believe in those thoughts, as long as you hate those thoughts your iman is still there . You should engage yourself in something like painting, reading, cooking, playing, stitching, writing, talking, etc so you can avoid these thoughts. When these thoughts come to your mind immediately start about something else.

Comment: Am I excused if I said a shirk statement but didn’t understand and said it accidentally and I wasn’t thinking at all??

Comment: Don't worry, it was not your intention so you are not sinful for this

Comment: Brother Jazakallah for your constant advice . But please make dua for me . Alhamdulillah Allah is always by my side. I have jinn possession. I say/think stuff that I regret or don’t mean to say or think that I said something but idk if  it was in my dream . Alhamdulillah Allah always guides me to seek his forgiveness. Whether I think I did something or not .

Comment: Ok I will make dua for you inshallah, you should contact someone who can help you to get rid of that jinn, I have a utube channel so if you like please subscribe to my channel- https://youtube.com/channel/UCzCxGaMEv3U2WlmqoCjH-8w

Comment: Jazakallah I will subscribe and comment and let you know it’s me . Also I have been to someone alhamdulillah

Comment: Thank you very much